# Cannot understand this piece of code (operator &) in C++

Tags: c++, operators

I don't understand why the & operator which mainly means "adress of" is there,
I used this operator in C but in this code I don't understand it's purpose.

```
#ifndef _STUDENT_
#define _STUDENT_

struct Student {
    char* name;
    int mark;
};

void InitStudent(Student&);
void ShowStudent(Student);
void DeleteStudent(Student&);

#endif
```

Comment: it marks "reference type" (semi-pointer) - something completely new (compared to C) in C++. Read some book / tutorial about C++ - C & C++ are completely different languages

Comment: A [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in) to look at.

Answer (score 7):

The `&` in `Student&` means that you are passing a (non-const) **reference** to a Student instance. It's not the C "address-of" operator.

Comment: What does the byte pattern of a reference correspond to? For pointers, it is easy to understand that their byte pattern is simply the memory address of the pointee. Or, for an integer say 5, it is 00...0101.